# Combine multiple filters in batch

Tags: batch-file, whatsapp

I'm trying to create a batch script that kills all frozen windows. For some reason WhatsApp on Desktop is depending on a frozen program, so running the following command will kill all frozen programs and create a windows popup which is annoying.

```
taskkill /F /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING"
```

I want to create the following thing

```
taskkill /F /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING & WINDOWTITLE ne WhatsApp"
```

But I can't manage to combine the filters.
What's the correct syntax?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply more than one filter, use the `/FI` switch more than once. Thus:

```
taskkill /F /FI "STATUS eq NOT RESPONDING" /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne WhatsApp"
```